# How to execute a simple Linux cmdline with PHP

Tags: php, linux

I just want to execute simple commands via network and process results with PHP.

Environment: Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon 64 bit vers. 3.0.6 (Linux Kernel 4.4.0-21-generic)

opt/lampp/htdocs/cmd.php

```
<?php
  //error_reporting(0);  
  error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

  // execute cmdline
  $output = array();
  exec('/usr/bin/sudo /var/sudowebscript.sh cmd=ifconfig', $output, $return_var); 

  echo $return_var;

  $response = $_GET["callback"]."(".json_encode($output).")";
  echo $response;
?>
```

/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini

```
; Safe Mode
; http://php.net/safe-mode
safe_mode=Off
```

/var/sudowebscript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# sudo web script allowing user www-data to run commands with root privilegs

case "$1" in
    cmd=iwconfig)
       /sbin/iwconfig
    ;;
    cmd=ifconfig)
       /sbin/ifconfig
    ;;      
   *) echo "ERROR: invalid parameter: $1 (for $0)"; exit 1 ;;
esac

exit 0
```

sudo visudo entry

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /var/sudowebscript.sh
```

permissions

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 gerhard gerhard 274 Nov  7 17:03 /var/sudowebscript.sh
```

user grouping (not sure if this is relevant ...)

```
gerhard@gerhard-ThinkPad-T400 ~ $ groups root
root : root
gerhard@gerhard-ThinkPad-T400 ~ $ groups gerhard
gerhard : gerhard adm cdrom sudo dip www-data plugdev lpadmin sambashare
gerhard@gerhard-ThinkPad-T400 ~ $ groups www-data
www-data : www-data
```

exec statement in cmd.php returns rc = 1 , nothing happens

I guess I am missing something ... thanks for help

Just noticed it works without the sudo (RC= 0 and $output populated)

```
exec('/var/sudowebscript.sh cmd=ifconfig', $output, $return_var);
```

But the original intention was also to execute cmd's requiring root privileges. (the ifconfig is just a simple example here)
Therefore also the .sh , keeping some security in mind ...

Maybe interesting. The setup as outlined above with sudo works perfect on a debian (raspberry) system. Even rebooting.

On the debian I must have something setup, I forgot here. Any ideas ?

Comment: Simply run your code with `shell_exec('ifconfig 2&>1')` in php instead of running through the `.sh` file.

Comment: thanks, but shell_exec('ifconfig 2&>1') returns nothing, just creates an empty file ...